# Case When returning multiple results for same primary key

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have created a CASE WHEN statement to create a 1 if a patient is in a specific bed type in the hospital and a 0 if not.  Since the table that is being used to create the flag has multiple beds for some patients, how can I make the flag unique to the patient visit?  For example I have a patient that was flagged as being in one of these beds but they also have a 0 because prior to that bed they were in a regular bed.  SO if I want to exclude the 1 patients this particular patient gets included in both counts since she has a 0 and a 1 due to the fact that she was transferred into one of these beds later in her visit. I want the flag to work as if the patient has ever been a 1 then to exclude them. 

Here is the logic I used

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#LOC')is not null
drop table #LOC
SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT DISTINCT LOC.EID
      ,CASE WHEN LOC.LOC_ROOM_CD_DESCR = 'PES' then '1'
       WHEN LOC.LOC_ROOM_CD_DESCR like '%obs%' then '2'
       ELSE '0' END as 'PESOBSFlag'
INTO #LOC
FROM [trackingtbl]LOC
with (nolock)
GROUP BY LOC.EID
      ,CASE WHEN LOC.LOC_ROOM_CD_DESCR = 'PES' then '1'
       WHEN LOC.LOC_ROOM_CD_DESCR like '%obs%' then '2'
       ELSE '0' END
```

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your question because your narrative just talks about two possibilities (0 and 1) but then your query has three possibilities. Also, you talk about counts in your narrative, and yet there's no counting happening in your query. And finally, I'm confused about why you're applying both `DISTINCT` and a `GROUP BY` across all columns. Could you maybe try to make your query match your narrative or vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in two stages:-

```
select eid, max(flag) as PESOBSFlag
from (
    select loc.EID,
    case
        when loc.LOC_ROOM_CD_DESCR = 'PES' then '1'
        when loc.LOC_ROOM_CD_DESCR like '%obs%' then '2'
        else '0' 
    end as flag
    from trackingtbl loc
) FirstPass
group by eid
```

The inner query simply translates the description into your number, with multiple rows per EID.  The outer query then pulls a single row together for each EID - and picks the highest flag value for each.